# Не могу разобраться с даггер 2 DI

Tags: java, android, dagger2, di, dagger

**Имеется класс:**

```
public class GameData {
    public final String hello = "Hello Dagger";
}
```

**Класс, который инжектит GameData:**

```
public class GameSession {
    @Inject
    public GameData data;
}
```

**GameModule, создающий зависимость GameData:**

```
@Module
public class GameModule {
    @Provides
    GameData providesGameData() {
        return new GameData();
    }
}
```

**Интерфейс компоненты:**

```
@Component(modules = GameModule.class)
public interface GameComponent {
    void inject(GameSession obj);
}
```

**С помощью тестов собираюсь запустить все это:**

```
public class GameSessionTest {
    @Test
    public void testGameSession(){
        GameSession session = new GameSession();
        DaggerGameComponent.create().inject(session);
        assertEquals("Hello Dagger", session.data.hello);
    }
}
```

Но класс `DaggerGameComponent` - не определяет, в чем проблема?

Comment: Класс `DaggerGameComponent` создастся во время сборки проекта, кстати как его собираете? Попробуйте заменить `DaggerGameComponent.create()` на `DaggerGameComponent.builder().build()`

Comment: @Maxim это я понял, но как сделать так , чтобы андроид студио не ругалось на него в момент сборки?

Comment: @Maxim аа как его нужно запускать?

Comment: Не заметил, что это андроид. Градл должен собрать его. Все три зависимости прописаны?

Comment: @Maxim только 2 implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.20'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'

Comment: `implementation'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15'`  
   `implementation'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15'`
   `annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'`

Comment: @Maxim ааа, точно. анотация процесс этим же занимается)

Comment: Там еще потребуется менять манифест, что бы прокинуть в модули applicationContext

Comment: @Maxim а где об этом можно почитать? напишите ответ , я его приму

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/345898/ в абзаце `Шаг 4. Создание класса Application`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По документации за генерацию DaggerGameComponent отвечает annotationProcessor `dagger:dagger-android-processor`.

`dependencies {
  implementation'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.x'
  implementation'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.x' // if you use the support libraries
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.x'
}`